# Troubles using GLEW 1.10.0 and SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl, glew

The following code produces 4 errors related to my use of sdl and glew functions.
I am using VS Express 2013 and have linked to the headers, libs, and placed dll's in the appropriate sys32/syswow64 folders. What could possibly be the problem?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include "glew.h"
    #include "SDL.h"

    int wmain(int argc, char ** argv[]){

    SDL_Window *sdl_Window;
    SDL_GLContext sdl_GL_Context;

    sdl_Window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2/OpenGL Demo", 0, 0, 640, 480,  
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    sdl_GL_Context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(sdl_Window);

    // init glew
    GLenum glewInitResult;

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glewInit();

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
    }
```

These are the errors:
        Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0 referenced in function _wmain

```
    Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateWindow referenced in function _wmain   

    Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GL_CreateContext referenced in function _wmain   

    Error 4 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewExperimental 

    Error 5 error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Link cannot find GLEW lib. Not sure how you would set this up in VS, but from the command line it involves adding -lGLEW.

Comment: Also trying increasing the build output verbosity: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity: Diagnostic

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues that you might want to check.

I had linking issues when I was linking to the incorrect architecture version of the lib file (x64 instead of x86)

You must make sure the directory containing the lib files is in the "additional library directories" property of the linker property page for the project in question

Answer (score 1):

Old post but if anyone has an issue with this: Make sure you have the header and library links correctly placed:

project/properties:
switch to all configurations:

c/c++ - general - additional include directories:
include all "include" files (glew 1.10 has an additional file inside of the include file named GL... you must link to this file.

linker/general - additional library directories:
the sdl libraries include a x64 or 86 file inside of the lib directory - you must link to either x64 or 86... glew1.10 has Release or ReleaseMX directory then Win32 or x64 inside of lib... you must link to either the win32 or x64 inside one of these directories

linker/input - additional dependencies:
include lib files  SDL2.lib; SDL2main.lib; glew32.lib; opengl32.lib; etc... etc...

Try this instead of placing in system folder:

solution explorer / right click on project name - open folder in file explorer
place dll's (glew32.dll - SDL2.dll) in project (debug and normal) directories

See if this works:

if not... start a new empty project and do this :)